# Add to Jquery-ui sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Simple question about [Jquery-UI sortable lists](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default)

I have made:

```
<div id="adder">
<input type="text" name="add1" /><br />
<input class='btn' type='submit' value='Submit' />
</div>
```

How can I use this to add what the user enters to the end of the jquery-ui sortable list?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Presumably, you would just take the text, wrap it in an LI with the class `ui-state-default` and insert it into the sortable UL element. You will then need to [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) the sortable to cause the newly inserted element to be recognised:

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $("input[name='add1']").val();
    var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(text);
    $("#sortable").append($li);
    $("#sortable").sortable('refresh');
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MvnEv/)

Comment: Thank you!, But how is this adding the </li> to the list item? Also, do you have more info on $ before a variable name like here with $li?

Comment: @David19801 - jQuery takes care of adding the closing tag. The `$` is just a common convention to mean *this variable holds a jQuery object*. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @karim79: jQuery (or -UI) also takes care of adding the <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"> with the new <li>? I don't see it explicitly in your fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: This helped me a lot to add an image to the sortable list, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `$("#sortable").sortable('refresh');` didn't worked.

But this worked: `$("#sortable").trigger("sortupdate");`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly the answer but @karim79 helped me to find a way to add an image to the sortable list, if anyone needs it here it is:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" style="width: 100%;" />
```

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>");
            $li.append('<img src="'+ e.target.result +'" width="150" height="200" />');
            $("#sortable").append($li);
            $("#sortable").sortable('refresh');
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").sortable('refresh')
```

works fine.

There is one more thing to be aware of:

```
handle: '.iORAS_ORD'
```

If you use handle with sortable, don't use jquery for selection, like:

```
handle: $('.iORAS_ORD')
```

If using jQuery, sorting after insert is not possible on newly inserted items. 
[More on the subject here.](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3794)