# jQuery UI sortable - drag element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two blocks, "draggable" and "sortable". Inside "draggable" I have few items which I can drag them to "sortable".

I want to have the possibility to click an item inside "draggable" and automatically drag it into "sortable".

Here is my JS:

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
   placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
});

$('.sortableList').disableSelection();

$(".draggable").draggable({
 connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
 cursor: 'pointer',
 helper: 'clone',
 revert: 'invalid',
 start: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).addClass('testing');
 }
});
```

and this is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fukutomometu/1/)

Any ideas how can I drag the elements to "sortable" by clicking on them ?

Comment: I think I'm not following. You want to be able to _create_ new `draggables` attached to the `sortable` list from the static items you have around?

Comment: No, I want to mimic the the behavior of dragging the element into the sortableList by clicking on the element I want to drag.

Comment: Ok, so you have items **outside** the sortable list and you want to add those you want, keeping others out, right?

Comment: Yes, you can see how the dragging works on the jsbin example. So I want to the same thing when I click on the items I normally have to drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler, tell it to append the target to the sortable. Then refresh the select.

http://jsbin.com/fukutomometu/5/

```
 $("#sidebar-wrapper").on("click", ".draggable", function(e){
     $(".sortableList").append(e.target).sortable('refresh');
 });
```

You can also add and remove relevant classes from target if you don't want it to be draggable anymore.

And `$.clone` instead of `$.append` if you don't want to move the original. And change the order a bit:

```
$(e.target).clone().appendTo(".sortableList");
```

Relevant question:

[Add to Jquery-ui sortable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804633/add-to-jquery-ui-sortable-list)

Comment: I've tried replacing append with clone but it doesn't work, any suggestions ?

Comment: @agis I've edited. Clone doesn't copyTo, it just clones and returns the clone.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the coding, it's with the lack of some css.

Add this:

```
.sortableList li {
   width:150px; /*This was already set*/
   height:250px;
   background-color:blue;
}
```

Also, consider using and `id` for the sortable list, not a class.