# jQuery UI sortable - do something on start and remove on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two block one is "draggable" and the other is "sortable".

When I start dragging an item from "sortable" I want to add a background color to a div and if I stop dragging it I want to remove the background color.

Here's my JS:

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
 start: function(event, ui) {

   if (event.handleObj.namespace=="sortable")
       $('.background').show();
    },

 update: function(event, ui) {

   if (event.handleObj.namespace=="sortable")
       $('.background').hide();
    }


});
$(".draggable").draggable({
 connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
 cursor: 'pointer',
 helper: 'clone',
 revert: 'invalid',
 start: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).addClass('testing');
 }
});
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/layifamolafe/2/edit) containing a live example of what I'm trying to do.

The problem is that when I start dragging an item from "sortable" and drop it in the same place it was the background color remains the same and I'm not expecting this.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you spent some time with the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) you might be able to [limit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26216281/2333214) the [rate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26192255/2333214) of [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26099807/2333214)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `stop` event instead of the `update` event:

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
 start: function(event, ui) {

   if (event.handleObj.namespace=="sortable")
       $('.background').show();
    },

 stop: function(event, ui) {

   if (event.handleObj.namespace=="sortable")
       $('.background').hide();
    }


});
```