# Jquery sortable not working after ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table filled with data from my database. This table is sortable and saves the order with ajax. Now I made the option to delete the selected row. When the row is deleted the table is refreshed with ajax.

My only problem now is when I delete a row and my table is refreshed, the table can't be sorted any more (until I refresh).

Is there a way to fix this?

This is my jquery/ajax code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sortable').sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'includes/saveorder.php'
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function deleteFromDatabase(id) {
        if (confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze pagina wilt verwijderen?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "includes/paginas_del.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block";
                    $("#myTable").load("paginas.php #myTable");
                }
            });
        } else {
            document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-cust" id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="80%">Pagina</th>
                <th width="10%"></th>
                <th width="10%"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="sortable">
            <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagina WHERE active = '1' ORDER BY sort");
                while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                    <tr id="item-<?php echo $data['id'] ?>">
                        <td><a href="paginas_edit.php?pagina_id=<?php print $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['titel'] ?></a></td>
                        <td><a href="paginas_edit.php?pagina_id=<?php print $data['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:deleteFromDatabase(<?php print $data['id']; ?>)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Can you also provide the HTML?

Comment: Use `$("#sortable").sortable('refresh');` - [Add to Jquery-ui sortable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804633/add-to-jquery-ui-sortable-list)

Comment: @Shai Added the table

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the fact that what the call to jquery's `load` method does is "load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element".

This means that the whole table is replaced with a new table. So the old `<tbody id="sortable">` element is replaced with a new one which doesn't have the `sortable` behavior you attached to the old one.

Try rerunning the `sortable` method after the table is rebuilt:

```
function deleteFromDatabase(id) {
    if (confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze pagina wilt verwijderen?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/paginas_del.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block";
                $("#myTable").load("paginas.php #myTable");

                $('#sortable').sortable({
                    axis: 'y',
                    update: function (event, ui) {
                        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

                        $.ajax({
                            data: data,
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'includes/saveorder.php'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. Also tried making the whole `$('#sortable').sortable` a function, and call that function there. But this also did not work.

Comment: What is the code that is returned by `paginas.php #myTable`?