# how to make inserted items sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
 containment: "parent",
 tolerance: "pointer",
 axis: "x"
 });
 
 $('button').on('click', function(){
 var str = $('#store').html();
 $(str).insertBefore($('.parent').eq(0));
 });
```

```css
.parent{
background:silver;
margin:9px 0;
}
.title{
background:gold;
display:inline-block;
width:25%;
cursor:cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='store'>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

How to make inserted items sortable?

I tried all solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804633/add-to-jquery-ui-sortable-list) and [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-add-a-new-element-to-sortable) and ...

Nothing works.

Comment: Need to run `refresh` on sortable after adding items: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: Do you want to clone the 2 items into the same list? Or are you truing to make a new list?

Comment: @Twisty, I need the new items to be sortable on the same way as old ones - inside its parent. `$( ".selector" ).sortable( "refresh" );` doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding items, you need to run `refresh`:

> Refresh the sortable items. Triggers the reloading of all sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.

In regards to placement, you appear to selecting more than you need. I suspect you just need to insert more items to the same list. Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parent').sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    axis: "x"
  });

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var str = $('#store .parent').html();
    $(str).insertBefore($('.parent div:eq(0)'));
    $('.parent').sortable("refresh");
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: silver;
  margin: 9px 0;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  cursor: cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='store'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='title'>lorem</div>
    <div class='title'>ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

If you need a new list, then you need to add it and re-assign sortable to the new item.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parent').sortable({
    containment: "parent",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    axis: "x"
  });

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var str = $('#store .parent:last').prop("outerHTML");
    $(str).insertBefore($('.parent:eq(0)'));
    $("#store .parent").sortable({
      containment: "parent",
      tolerance: "pointer",
      axis: "x"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: silver;
  margin: 9px 0;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  cursor: cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='store'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='title'>lorem</div>
    <div class='title'>ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, it works. And what is `refresh` function on your link. You didn't use it.

Comment: @puerto since we are not adding new items to the same list, I did not need to. We created new list and re-initialized sortable for the new items.